# get rid of duplicate values in the search results / angular2 / typescript / js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to get rid of duplicate values in the search results.
Please, help me to find a simple solution.

my ***buyer-search.service.ts*** :

```js
export class BuyerSearchService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    search(term: string, atrib: string): Observable<Buyer[]> {
        return this.http
            .get(`app/buyers/?${atrib}=${term}`)
            .map((r: Response) => r.json().data as Buyer[]);
    }
}
```

my ***buyer-search.component.ts***

```js
export class BuyerSearchComponent implements OnInit {

    buyers: Observable<Buyer[]>;
    private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
    constructor(
        private buyerSearchService: BuyerSearchService,        
        private router: Router) {}
    // Push a search term into the observable stream.
    search(term: string): void {
        this.searchTerms.next(term);       
    } 

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.buyers = this.searchTerms
            .debounceTime(300)        // wait for 300ms pause in events
            .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
            .switchMap(term => term   // switch to new observable each time
                // return the http search observable
                ? this.buyerSearchService.search(term, 'clientName')
                // or the observable of empty buyers if no search term
                : Observable.of<Buyer[]>([]))
            .catch(error => {
                // TODO: real error handling
                console.log(error);
                return Observable.of<Buyer[]>([]);
            });
    }   
}
```

and View, ***buyer-search.component.html*** :

```html
<div id="search-component">
    <input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)"/>  
    <div id="buyerByNameResults">
        <div *ngFor="let buyer of buyers | async"
              class="search-result">
            <p class="buyer-name-s">{{buyer.clientName}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snCla.png)

Comment: You should note that `r.json().data as Buyer[]);` will NOT produce an array of typed objects. It will still only return an object literal. **Type assertion is NOT type casting**. This means any class methods/property accessors will not be available on those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to perform a .distinct() on the inner observable, and pass a key selector to the first parameter.

```
this.buyerSearchService
    .search(term, 'clientName')
    .distinct(function (x) { return x.clientName; });
```

There is a second parameter which allows you to supply a comparer, if needed.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinct.md